# Центрирование div блока

Tags: css, css3

Столкнулся с проблемой при выводе модального окна ( обычный div блок ). Надо расположить по центру, выровняв по вертикали. Проблема в том, что высота блока не определена ( у меня это вывод комментария юзера ). Слышал про использование display table, но он не подходит, так как нужна прокрутка внутри блока. 
Раньше использовал:

```
.elX{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Подскажите что делать!

Answer (score 0):

```
.elX{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```